# Looping to group data columns

Tags: r

I'm relatively new to R. I've been trying to experiment with looping through the for() argument.

I have dummy data sets that follow this pattern:

```
Date    EUR HIGH    EUR LOW EUR CLOSE   JPY CURNCY  JPY LOW JPY CLOSE   GBP CURNCY  GBP CURNCY  GBP CURNCY
8/30/2016   1.12    1.12    1.12    102.56  101.76  102.50  1.31    1.31    1.31
8/29/2016   1.12    1.12    1.12    102.39  101.84  101.92  1.32    1.32    1.32
8/28/2016   1.13    1.12    1.12    101.94  100.06  101.84  1.33    1.33    1.33
8/27/2016   1.13    1.12    1.12    101.94  100.06  101.84  1.33    1.33    1.33
8/26/2016   1.13    1.12    1.12    101.94  100.06  101.84  1.33    1.33    1.33
8/25/2016   1.13    1.13    1.13    100.62  100.30  100.53  1.33    1.33    1.33
8/24/2016   1.13    1.12    1.13    100.61  100.10  100.45  1.33    1.33    1.33
8/23/2016   1.14    1.13    1.13    100.39  99.94   100.24  1.32    1.32    1.32
8/22/2016   1.13    1.13    1.13    100.93  100.21  100.33  1.32    1.32    1.32
8/21/2016   1.14    1.13    1.13    100.46  99.88   100.22  1.32    1.32    1.32
8/20/2016   1.14    1.13    1.13    100.46  99.88   100.22  1.32    1.32    1.32
8/19/2016   1.14    1.13    1.13    100.46  99.88   100.22  1.32    1.32    1.32
```

Since I have various Excel files that follows this pattern organization (i.e: price low, high and close), I'm trying to create a function that would merge the three variables (low, high, close) and the date into a table. The idea behind this is that I would like to have a separate table generated for each individual currency so that a separate analysis can be done for each individual currency and then have it loop through all the currencies, if that makes sense.

So ideally, I would want R to generate a table like:

```
Date   Euro High   Euro Close  Euro low
1/1    1.15        1.13        1.12
1/2    1.15        1.13        1.12
1/3    1.15        1.13        1.12
```

And then I'll have R do some basic analysis, and then have it repeat the process for the next variable (GBP, JPY). I'm having a little trouble on the grouping part.

My code is incredibly wrong (and also probably a major eyesore), but it might be useful in pointing out improvements/errors:

```
Data.Prep = function(x){ 
for(i in seq(1))
 {
   dates = as.Date(x[,i], format="%m/%d/$Y")
 }

for(i in seq(2, length(x)))
 {
   x[,i] = as.numeric(as.character(x[,i]))
 }

for(i in seq(2, length(x), 3))  
 {
  x1 = x[i:(i-1)]
 }

}
```

x1 returns:

```
   GBP.CURNCY JPY.CLOSE
1      1.3120    102.50
2      1.3172    101.92
3      1.3279    101.84
4      1.3279    101.84
5      1.3279    101.84
6      1.3264    100.53
7      1.3273    100.45
8      1.3211    100.24
9      1.3157    100.33
10     1.3185    100.22
11     1.3185    100.22
12     1.3185    100.22
```

Comment: You dont need a loop here. you just need to subset the data. try this `i=grep('EUR',names(x));x[,c(1,i)]`.

Comment: You will have better luck if you don't allow spaces in your column names. I'm guessing this is a tab-separated file and sep ='\t' would be the argument for the table read.

Answer (score 3):

You could do this, but you should which currency to feed. Here i feed a vector of currency which would then retrieve the column indices. Then we would could just do a standard sub-setting.

```
vec=c('EUR', 'JPY', 'GBP' )
i=sapply(vec, function(y) grep(y,names(x)), USE.NAMES = F)
apply(i,2, function(i) x[c(1,i)] )
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! This works exactly how I wanted it to work. Thanks again, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Hi, sorry for posting again but I'm receiving an error saying   dim(X) must have a positive length. I changed the vectors to include all the names of my currencies, so I have vec=c('EUR', 'JPY', 'GBP', 'CHF', 'AUD', 'CAD', 'NZD', 'SEK', 'NOK', 'CZK', 'HUF', 'ILS', 'PLN', 'RUB',
+ 'TRY', 'ZAR', 'BRL', 'CLP', 'COP', 'MXN', 'PEN', 'CNY', 'IDR', 'INR', 'KRW', 'MYR', 'SGD', 'PHP', 'THB'). Thanks!

Comment: please share `dput(X)`. Also why do you have `+` in the `vec` you created.